# Can I make heroku multiple web dynos formation and routing by subdomain?

Tags: heroku

I use heroku web and worker dynos.
And now I want to split requests by subdomain or path.

for example

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT ./config/puma
admin-web: bundle exec puma -p $PORT ./config/puma
worker: ...
```

- www.example.com -> web dynos
- admin.example.com -> admin-web dynos

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot do this. Domains are routed to dynos at the Heroku application level.

If you want to do this, you'll need to create two separate Heroku applications -- or, a much simpler idea: have only one type of web server, and parse the incoming URL. If the URL starts with `admin.`, then display content for admins, if the URL starts with `www.`, then display non-admin content =)

Comment: Now I have only one type of web server and parse URL. But Admin request is very heavy and it effects `www` request. That's why I want to split dynos.

Comment: Sorry! As I said, there is no way to do what you're asking. You might want to look into optimizing your admin requests, or running them as separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by using two Procfiles and the [Multi-Procfile Buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi-procfile), one for `web`, one for `admin-web`. It's described in detail [here](https://medium.com/inato/how-to-setup-heroku-with-yarn-workspaces-d8eac0db0256).